# _youtubeController.close() in dispose doesn't work as expected

Tags: flutter, dart, youtube, youtube-player-flutter

I'm using [youtube_player_iframe](https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_player_iframe/) package for flutter web. The issue I'm facing is that if I start playing a youtube video and then go to another screen, the video is still playing in the background.

I've included the dispose and close of the controller, but it doesn't work.

```
import 'dart:developer';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:youtube_player_iframe/youtube_player_iframe.dart';

class AddYoutubeVideo extends StatefulWidget {
  final String videoUrl;
  const AddYoutubeVideo({Key? key, required this.videoUrl}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AddYoutubeVideo> createState() => _AddYoutubeVideoState();
}

class _AddYoutubeVideoState extends State<AddYoutubeVideo> {
  late YoutubePlayerController _youtubeController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _youtubeController = YoutubePlayerController(
      initialVideoId: YoutubePlayerController.convertUrlToId(widget.videoUrl)!,
      params: const YoutubePlayerParams(
        showControls: true,
        showFullscreenButton: true,
        autoPlay: false,
      ),
    );
    _youtubeController.onEnterFullscreen = () {
      SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
        DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
        DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
      ]);
    };
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose(); // Have tried to use super.dispose below the close() also
    _youtubeController.close();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return YoutubePlayerIFrame(
      controller: _youtubeController,
      aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
    );
  }
}
```

I'm then using this class to display two youtube videos simply with:

```
AddYoutubeVideo(videoUrl: url1)),
```

Is there anything that I've done wrong or should have been doing instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By moving to the next screen I assume that you are performing Navigator.push or Navigator.pushNamed

On both the cases the screen stays at the stack and will definitely play at the background. If you are moving to another screen. You can try

```
Navigator.pushReplacement

//or

Navigator.pushReplacementNamed

//or to go to Previous screen you can pop the current screen

Navigator.pop(context);
```

In all the 3 cases the dispose is called.

Comment: Thank you! I removed my dispose, and replace the Navigator to Navigator.pushReplacementNamed, and it's working fine now.

Comment: You can add dispose too. Its better to dispose unused controllers. Glad it worked as expected :)